# Why do I get data model error only concrete types can conform to protocols

Tags: swiftui

I want to separate my data model from the ContentView. So I added a SwiftUI file with the following code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class User: BindableObject {
    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    var username : String = "Jan" { willSet { willChange.send() }}
    var password : String = "123456" { willSet { willChange.send() } }
    var emailAddress : String = "jan@mail.nl" { willSet { willChange.send() } }
}

#if DEBUG
struct User_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        User()
            .environmentObject(User())
    }
}
#endif
```

The error I get is:

```
Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'View' because only concrete types can conform to protocols
```

Error occurs in the .environmentObject(User()) line.

Comment: What line do you get the error message on?

Comment: In the Previewprovider, first 'User(username:... ' occurrence.

Comment: Where's your initializer? You need to either make `User` a `struct`, or add a custom init function to take the username, password and email properties.

Comment: I've reposted the question with more information and code, Linus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a SwiftUI File. Its a simple class which is required. Of course if you remove the code below it will work.

```
#if DEBUG
struct User_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        User()
            .environmentObject(User())
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: So because it is a Class and not a Struct, I don't need a SwiftUI file?

Comment: The SwiftUI file is only a template and you can add any content and rename it as well but PreviewProvider is not required in your case. If you want to create. class or struct use the Swift file template. If you want to get a SwiftUI view choose the SwiftUI template.